# Magento2 - How do I generate a list or orders a vaulted payment method has been used for?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, payment-methods

I am trying to generate a list of orders that a vaulted card (Braintree) has been used for.

I have a payment instance from an order, and I'm trying to establish if the vaulted card has been used for previous successful orders.

How do I go about generating a list of orders using the same stored payment method, as a given order?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method is to go to Admin -> Sales -> Transactions and filter the grid by a payment method. In that way, you will get a list of orders with chosen payment method.
Hope it will help.